# Using the Google maps API with JavaScript or PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, api, google-maps

i've read that you can use either javascript or php with google maps api. so what are the pros and cons for each of them?

and if i got the geocodes stored in a database. should i get them with ajax and process them with javascript or should i use php?

it says in the FAQ that 15000 requests are allowed per day per ip. does this mean that EACH user has to run 15000 requests a day if im using javascript? sounds a lot. but if im using php instead, is it from the server's ip only, and thus 15000 for ALL users?

would be great if someone could shed a light on this topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Google Maps API is a JavaScript library. However Google offers its Geocoding Services through a [client-side API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/services.html#Geocoding) in JavaScript and though a [server-side web service](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/index.html).

This is an example on how to use the JavaScript geocoder:

```
function initialize() {
  if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
    map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));

    geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();

    geocoder.getLatLng(
      "London, UK",
      function(point) {
        if (point) {
          map.setCenter(point, 13);
          var marker = new GMarker(point);
          map.addOverlay(marker);
        }
      }
    );
  }
}
```

The following is an example showing how to get the latitude and longitude of an address on the server-side using php:

```
$url = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=London,+UK&output=csv&sensor=false';

$data = @file_get_contents($url);

$result = explode(",", $data);

echo $result[0]; // status code
echo $result[1]; // accuracy
echo $result[2]; // latitude
echo $result[3]; // longitude
```

You understood the free geocoding quota correctly. Server-side geocoding is limited to 15k requests per day per server, while client-side geocoding is limited to 15k requests per day per client. You would need the [Google Maps API Premier](http://www.google.com/enterprise/earthmaps/maps.html) to increase these limits.

Comment: so its much better to request with javascript cause then it will be 15000 per user?

Comment: Sometimes you might need to do the geocoding on server, for example if your server is receiving GPS coordinates from a tracking device. But if you can use JavaScript, your limits are much bigger.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confused. The only part of the API that you can use PHP with is the geocoding api - http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/index.html

Assuming you are asking whether you should do your geocoding with javascript or a server side language like PHP, best practice is to cache whatever geocoding you can into some sort of persistance layaer (xml/db/whatever) and minimise the number of client side geocode requests (because of the delay it will introduce)